# document.getElementById('foo').src='' is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website using twitter bootstrap. When developing sometimes the internet is not working so jquery won't be loaded and my site will not work. This is why I have a local copy of jquery in my js folder. I edited bootstrap files so if jquery is not detected the browser will change the location of jquery from cdn to my local file. I tried to do that but it is not working:Here is my code:

```
if (!window.jQuery) {
  document.getElementById('jq').src='../../js/jquery.js';
  console.log("You are using a backup file of jquery provided by our website");
}
else{
  console.log("jQuery has been succesfully loaded by kounelios13");
}
```

html:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" id="jq"></script>
        <script src="../../js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../../js/prefixfree.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../../js/apps/rgba.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This is placed inside bootstrap's js file.
Any ideas???

Comment: The js code is written inside bootstap.js

Comment: better solution is to make a local copy of jquery instead of relying on the internet to load it.

Comment: Better approach is to add the js in your solution instead of link. If the file at the link changes, your code might not work.

Comment: @DLeh There is multiple reasons why loading jQuery via CDN is better than hosting a local copy. Using a fallback in case the connection is lost (or something) is recommended and encouraged.

Comment: @DLeh true, but in any case, I think that this is a good question and deserve a true answer, not just push the problem for later ;)

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon yeah, you're right. I deleted my comment shortly after writing it because of this reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imaging that CDN file is not available. Then browser starts loading next script file (`bootstrap.js`), parser enters `bootstrap.js`, where you placed your check for jQuery. Your code detects that jQuery is not loaded and the script then changes `src` of the `jq` tag. It works fine and jQuery starts loading, however browser doesn't wait until jQuery is downloaded and carry on to the Bootstrap stuff, which fails immediately, because it requires jQuery. Hence the error.

You can try this version for backup jQuery library instead which should be reliable:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" id="jq"></script>
<script>
if (!window.jQuery) {
    document.write("<script src='../../js/jquery.js'>\x3C/script>");
} 
</script>
<script src="../../js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../js/prefixfree.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../js/apps/rgba.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: do we need if (!window.jQuery) condition.

Answer (score 1):

With jquery I don't thinks bootstrap script work so you need that.

If you have internet problem then you can copy jquery link and make file of that and attached.

Comment: Then changes in HTML script src

Comment: and remove javascript

Answer (score 0):

ID must unique for the Document, you have another Element that uses the id `jq` or none.

Comment: I have 5 html pages.Every page uses that script with that id but in the   specific page this id is unique

Comment: Not at the time the script executes!